# Join to table with a condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have table of clients and I need to join to another table with two conditions.

For example in the join table I have `cancellation` table :

| ID | timestamp | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1555 | 1005 | NULL |
| 1555 | NULL | NULL |
| 1566 | R*1005 | NULL |
| 1566 | R*243 | 12 |
| 1566 | R*4918 | 8305 |
| 10M95 | R*9017 | 8305 |
| 10M95 | R*9470 | 8221 |

I need to find a client id 156 that has timestamp not null and value that is not null of the same row so for example id 1566 would join but not 1555 also the join must return only one row

```
SELECT 
    client.createdon, client.id,
    domain.paymentprofileid AS paymentprofileid
FROM 
    Clients AS client
JOIN 
    cancellation AS cancel ON client.id = cancel.customer_id
WHERE 
    cancel.timestamp IS NOT NULL
    AND cancel.value IS NULL
```

Comment: what exactly is your question? If you want to select each id only once, use the keyword DISTINCT, i.e. "SELECT DISTINCT client.id..."

Comment: Please take time to review your question. 'I need to find a client id 156' is never going to work given there are no id's with 156 in cancellations - 'timestamp not null and value that is not null' is not what the query tests - 'domain.paymentprofileid ' - this table is not invoked or mentioned in the question

Comment: where is join with domain table

Comment: Can you add the expected answer in your question? the requirement is not clear in your question.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing from the context that by 156 you mean 1566.

If I understand correctly then you're looking for any rows in the client table that have 1 or more rows in the cancellation table with both a timestamp and value that are not null.

I've removed the reference to domain table.

```
SELECT 
    client.createdon, 
    client.id
FROM 
    Clients AS client
WHERE client.id in (
    SELECT customer_id
    FROM cancellation 
    WHERE timestamp IS NOT NULL
       AND cancel.value IS NULL
)
```

Hope this helps, though its tough to be sure if this is what was meant by your question.

As previous posts have mentioned, please try and phrase your question clearly so it can be understood.